# setImageBitmap throw null error when i try to change ImageView in another layout

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, screenshot

I have 2 layouts `Activity_Main` and `screenshot`. i want to take screenshot from the `Activity_Main` and display it in `screenshot`

in `onCreate` this method:

```
public void bind (){
        screenshotViewCtrl = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.screenshotView);
        rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl) ;}
```

and here is the method to take screenshot and display in `screenshot`

```
public void save() {
       View rootView = rl.getRootView(); //Activity_Main
       rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
       Bitmap bitmap =Bitmap.createBitmap(rootView.getDrawingCache());
       rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
       String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
       File myDir = new File(root + "/me");
       myDir.mkdirs();

       final Dialog savePicDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
       savePicDialog.setTitle("edit name");
       savePicDialog.setContentView(R.layout.screenshot);

       EditText imgNameTxt = (EditText) savePicDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtPicName);
       Date date = new Date();
       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HHmm");
       String dateString = sdf.format(date);
       imgNameTxt.setText(dateString);
       String name = imgNameTxt.getText().toString();

       file = new File(myDir, name + ".png");

       try {
           file.createNewFile();
           FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
           bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, ostream);
           ostream.flush();
           ostream.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       String filePath = file.getPath();
       Bitmap selectedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
       screenshotViewCtrl.setImageBitmap(selectedBitmap);

       Button saveBtn = (Button) savePicDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
       saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

               newGame();
               savePicDialog.cancel();
           }
       });
       Button deleteBtn = (Button) savePicDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
       deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               file.delete();
               savePicDialog.cancel();
           }
       });
       savePicDialog.show();}
```

the XML of `screenshot`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/l1">
     <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/screenshotView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtPicName"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="alzahrani.alaa.myapp" >
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

the problem is in `screenshotViewCtrl.setImageBitmap(selectedBitmap);` it throw a null error! i tried to show the screenshot in the same layout and it worked fine! but when i try to show it in "screenshot" layout it give me this error.
and one more things. when i create the screenshot it doesnt show up in the studio until reopen the AVD! is that normal?

thanks.

Comment: Looks like `R.id.screenshotView` isn't found, resulting in `screenshotViewCtrl` being null. Post the exception you're getting. Are you sure `bind()` is called before `save()`?

Comment: Yes the `bind()` is in `OnCreate` and `save()` is in `OnClickListener`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to zsolt.kocsi. this the code after editing:

```
public void save() {
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View scrnShotLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screenshot, null);

       screenshotViewCtrl = (ImageView) scrnShotLayout.findViewById(R.id.screenshotView);
       ...//same old
       savePicDialog.setContentView(menuLayout);

       ...//same
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The NullPointerException you have surely originates from screenshotViewCtrl being null.

You initialized it in your code by:
screenshotViewCtrl = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.screenshotView);

So, findViewById returns null. This means it cannot find a view with that id. You didn't post your onCreate() method, not your Activity_Main.xml, but I take it you are inflating one of your two layouts, but trying to find a view defined in the other. You cannot do that, and Android won't warn you: it will just return null if it cannot find what you are looking for.

Make sure you are inflating your screenshot.xml and not Activity_Main.xml, if you'd like to access view from that.

Comment: I will try to inflate `screenshot.xml` as a child of `Activity_Main.xml`.